# Sorting considers records only on first page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have used jquery plugin tablesorter to sort objects by column.Sorting is working fine.I have a set of about 12 records in a list which works inside a table with pagination, 10 records per page and sorting enabled on all the columns.When the page loads , the sorting works only for those 10 records .It doesn't consider the other 2 records on the next page.When I click on the first column , the record on next page should come up first according to sorting as its name starts with alphabet 'A'.The whole point of my implementation was if there are many records , sorting should bring them up on the first page. what am i missing here.

Below is my VF page and apex class

VF

```
<apex:page controller="PSS_PendingMilestonesControllerNew"  >  

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'themes/blue/style.css')}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();    
    $j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("[id$=pendingMilestones]").tablesorter();

    });

  //some other unrelated js
    function reInitializeTableSorter() {
        $j("[id$=details]").tablesorter();
    }
</script>

    <apex:form id="theform" >  
     <div style="overflow:auto;height:500px">
     <!-- ******* Section Of Pending milestones whose actual recieved date is not null  ********   -->  
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" title="Pending Milestones"> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
            <apex:outputPanel id="myButtons" >
                    <apex:commandButton value="First" status="aStatus" action="{!firstPage}" title="First" disabled="{!IF(currentpage > 0,false,true)}" rendered="{!IF(DisplayList.size > 0,true,false)}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Previous" status="aStatus" action="{!previous}" title="Previous" disabled="{!IF(currentpage > 0,false,true)}" rendered="{!IF(DisplayList.size > 0,true,false)}"  />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Next" status="aStatus" action="{!next}" title="Next" disabled="{!IF(currentpage < (totalpages-1),false,true)}" rendered="{!IF(DisplayList.size > 0,true,false)}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Last" status="aStatus" action="{!lastPage}" title="Last" disabled="{!IF(currentpage < (totalpages-1),false,true)}" rendered="{!IF(DisplayList.size > 0,true,false)}"  onComplete="reInitializeTableSorter()"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>

          <apex:outputPanel id="myTable" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">      
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="pendingMilestones" value="{!displayList}" var="wrap" rendered="{!DisplayList.size>0}"  styleClass="tablesorter" headerClass="header">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Category">
                        <apex:outputtext styleClass="header" value="{!wrap.objName}"/>                                 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!wrap.sobj['Id']}" target="_blank" >{!wrap.sobj['Name']}</apex:outputLink>                                 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Actual Recieved Date">
                        <apex:outputtext styleClass="header" value="{!wrap.field2}"/>                   
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Actual Start Date">
                        <apex:outputtext styleClass="header" value="{!wrap.field3}"/>                   
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Target Complete Date">
                        <apex:outputtext styleClass="header" value="{!wrap.field4}"/>                   
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Priority">
                        <apex:outputtext styleClass="header" value="{!wrap.field5}"/>                   
                    </apex:column> 
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="No records to display." rendered="{!DisplayList.size=0}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 
           </apex:outputPanel> 

        </apex:pageBlock>

    <!-- ******* Section Of Incoming milestones whose actual recieved date is null  ********   -->    

        <apex:pageBlock id="pb2" title="Incoming Tasks"> 
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
            <apex:outputPanel id="myButtons" >
                    <apex:commandButton value="First" status="aStatus" action="{!firstPage1}" title="First" disabled="{!IF(currentpage1 > 0,false,true)}" rendered="{!IF(DisplayList1.size > 0,true,false)}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Previous" status="aStatus" action="{!previous1}" title="Previous" disabled="{!IF(currentpage1 > 0,false,true)}" rendered="{!IF(DisplayList1.size > 0,true,false)}"  />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Next" status="aStatus" action="{!next1}" title="Next" disabled="{!IF(currentpage1 < (totalpages1-1),false,true)}" rendered="{!IF(DisplayList1.size > 0,true,false)}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Last" status="aStatus" action="{!lastPage1}" title="Last" disabled="{!IF(currentpage1 < (totalpages1-1),false,true)}" rendered="{!IF(DisplayList1.size > 0,true,false)}"  />
            </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>

          <apex:outputPanel id="myTable1" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">      
                <apex:pageBlockTable id="IncomingMilestones" value="{!DisplayList1}" var="wrap" rendered="{!DisplayList1.size>0}">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Category">
                        <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.objName}"/>                                 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!wrap.sobj['Id']}" target="_blank" >{!wrap.sobj['Name']}</apex:outputLink>                                 
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Priority">
                        <apex:outputtext value="{!wrap.field5}"/>                   
                    </apex:column>  
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="No records to display." rendered="{!DisplayList1.size=0}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>  
          </apex:outputPanel>  
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex

```
public class PSS_PendingMilestonesControllerNew{

    public List<PSS_Milestone__c> pendingMilestoneList; //List retrieved on quering PSS Milestones
    public List<PSS_Milestone__c> sListPending = new List<PSS_Milestone__c>(); //Final List of PSS Milestone after filtering
    public integer currentpage {get;set;}
    public integer totalRecords {get;set;}
    public integer pageSize {get;set;}

    public integer currentpage1 {get;set;}
    public integer totalRecords1 {get;set;}
    public integer pageSize1 {get;set;}

    public List<wrapperPendingMilestone> wrapperListShow {get;set;}
    public List<wrapperPendingMilestone> wrapperListShowIncoming {get;set;}

    public List<wrapperPendingMilestone> displayList {get{
          system.debug('wrapperPendingMilestone>>>>'+wrapperListShow);
          List<wrapperPendingMilestone> displayList = new List<wrapperPendingMilestone>();
          totalRecords = wrapperListShow.size();

                if(wrapperListShow.size() > 0 && totalRecords > 0){
                    for(Integer i = currentpage*pageSize ; i < totalRecords && i < (currentpage*pageSize) + pageSize; i++){
                        displayList.add(wrapperListShow[i]);
                    }
                }
            return displayList;

        }set;}  //  For pending task section
    public List<wrapperPendingMilestone> displayList1 {get{
                system.debug('wrapperPendingMilestoneIncomming>>>>'+wrapperListShowIncoming);
                List<wrapperPendingMilestone> displayList1 = new List<wrapperPendingMilestone>();
                totalRecords1 = wrapperListShowIncoming.size();

                if(wrapperListShowIncoming.size() > 0 && totalRecords1 > 0){
                    for(Integer i = currentpage1*pageSize1 ; i < totalRecords1 && i < (currentpage1*pageSize1) + pageSize1; i++){
                        displayList1.add(wrapperListShowIncoming[i]);
                    }
                }
            return displayList1;

        }set;} //For Incoming task section

    /*-----------Parent Constructor---------*/

    public PSS_PendingMilestonesControllerNew(){

       currentpage=0;
       totalRecords = 0;
       pageSize = 10;

        currentpage1=0;
       totalRecords1 = 0;
       pageSize1 = 10;

        Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        wrapperListShow = new List<wrapperPendingMilestone>();
        wrapperListShowIncoming = new List<wrapperPendingMilestone>();


        /*------Get list of all the child records of PSS Opportunity that are eligible based on the conditions-------*/

        pendingMilestoneList = new List<PSS_Milestone__c>([Select id,name,Assigned_To__c ,Actual_Completed_Date__c,Actual_Received_Date__c,
                                        Actual_Start_Date__c,Target_Completed_Date__c,PSS_Queue__c,RecordType.Name,Priority__c,
                                        PSS_Milestone__c.PSS_Queue__r.Queue_Owner__c,PSS_Milestone__c.PSS_Queue__r.Backup_User1__c,
                                        PSS_Milestone__c.PSS_Queue__r.Backup_User2__c  
                                        from PSS_Milestone__c 
                                        where (Assigned_To__c =: userId or 
                                               (PSS_Milestone__c.PSS_Queue__r.Queue_Owner__c =: userId or
                                               PSS_Milestone__c.PSS_Queue__r.Backup_User1__c =: userId or 
                                               PSS_Milestone__c.PSS_Queue__r.Backup_User2__c =: userId)) and
                                              Actual_Completed_Date__c = null
                                        order by Target_Completed_Date__c DESC NULLS LAST]);


        /*--------Iterate over the individual child records list and add it to SObject list----------*/ 

            if(pendingMilestoneList.size() > 0){
                for(PSS_Milestone__c milestone : pendingMilestoneList ){

                    if((milestone.Assigned_To__c == milestone.PSS_Queue__r.Queue_Owner__c && 
                        (milestone.PSS_Queue__r.Queue_Owner__c == userId ||
                         milestone.PSS_Queue__r.Backup_User1__c == userId ||
                         milestone.PSS_Queue__r.Backup_User2__c == userId)) || 
                         (milestone.Assigned_To__c == userId)){

                               sListPending.add(milestone);                            
                        }             
                    }
                system.debug('**sListPending**'+sListPending);
            }


        /*----------Pass the List and get required details and put it in Wrapper List--------------*/    
        getDetialList(sListPending);
        system.debug('--displayList--'+displayList);
        system.debug('--displayList1--'+displayList1);

    }


    /*---------Get the details of the records retrieved in PSS Milestone list and add them to Wrapperlist----------*/

    public void getDetialList(List<PSS_Milestone__c> pendingMilestoneList){
        system.debug('**pendingMilestoneListPending inside function**'+pendingMilestoneList);

        /*-----Iterate over the Sobject list and add it to Wrapper list along with the required fields if present on the object------*/        
        for(PSS_Milestone__c s : pendingMilestoneList){
            Date d;
            String objName;
            objName = s.RecordType.Name;
            system.debug('---objName---'+objName);             

            /*-----Check for Actual_Received_Date__c field in SObject-----*/
            String d2;
                if(s.get('Actual_Received_Date__c') != null){
                   d = Date.valueOf(s.get('Actual_Received_Date__c'));
                   d.format();               
                   system.debug('Date value...'+d);           
                   d2 = String.valueOf(d);
                   system.debug('String value...'+d2);               
                }


            /*-----Check for Actual_Start_Date__c field in SObject-----*/           
            String d3;

                if(s.get('Actual_Start_Date__c') != null){
                   d = Date.valueOf(s.get('Actual_Start_Date__c'));
                   system.debug('Date value...'+d);         
                   d3 = String.valueOf(d);
                   system.debug('String value...'+d3);               
                }


            /*-----Check for Target_Completed_Date__c field in SObject-----*/            
            String d4;

                if(s.get('Target_Completed_Date__c') != null){
                    d = Date.valueOf(s.get('Target_Completed_Date__c'));
                    system.debug('Date value...'+d);           
                    d4 = String.valueOf(d);
                    system.debug('String value...'+d4);                
                }

            /*-----Check for Target_Completed_Date__c field in SObject-----*/            
            String d5;

                if(s.get('Priority__c') != null){         
                    d5 = String.valueOf(s.get('Priority__c'));
                    system.debug('String value...'+d5);                
                }


            /*-------Add the records to WrapperList along with the retrieved parameters--------*/
            // if actual recieved date is not null add in list
             if(s.get('Actual_Received_Date__c') != null) 
             {
                wrapperListShow.add(new wrapperPendingMilestone(s,objName,d2,d3,d4,d5));  
             }  

             else
                wrapperListShowIncoming.add(new wrapperPendingMilestone(s,objName,d3,d4,d5));         
        }

        system.debug('****wrapperListShow***'+wrapperListShow);
    }

    //---------------methods for PAGINATION for WrapperListShow --------------

    public Integer getTotalPages() {
      if (math.mod(totalRecords, Pagesize ) > 0) {
         return totalRecords/Pagesize + 1;
      } else {
         return (totalRecords/Pagesize);
      }
   }

    public Integer getTotalPages1() {
      if (math.mod(totalRecords1, Pagesize1 ) > 0) {
         return totalRecords1/Pagesize1 + 1;
      } else {
         return (totalRecords1/Pagesize1);
      }
    }

    public void firstPage() { //user clicked First button
      currentpage=0;
    }

    public void previous() { //user clicked previous button
      currentpage--;
    }

    public void next() { //user clicked next button
      currentpage++;
    }

    public void lastPage() { //user clicked last button
      if(math.mod(totalRecords,pageSize) == 0){
          currentpage = (totalRecords / pageSize) - 1;
      }
      else{
          currentpage = totalRecords / pageSize;
      }
    }

    //---------------methods for PAGINATION for WrapperListShow --------------
    public void firstPage1() { //user clicked First button
      currentpage1=0;
    }

    public void previous1() { //user clicked previous button
      currentpage1--;
    }

    public void next1() { //user clicked next button
      currentpage1++;
    }

    public void lastPage1() { //user clicked last button
      if(math.mod(totalRecords1,pageSize1) == 0){
          currentpage1 = (totalRecords1 / pageSize1) - 1;
      }
      else{
          currentpage1 = totalRecords1 / pageSize1;
      }


    }
    //-----------------------------------------------

    /*--------Wrapper Class--------*/
    public class wrapperPendingMilestone{
        public SObject sobj {get;set;}
        public String objName {get;set;}
        public String field2 {get;set;}
        public String field3 {get;set;}
        public String field4 {get;set;}
        public String field5 {get;set;}    


        /*---------Wraper Constructor--for section where-Actual Recieved date not null------*/
        public wrapperPendingMilestone(SObject sobj, String objName, String field2, String field3,String field4,String field5){
            this.sobj = sobj;
            this.objName = objName;           
            this.field2 = field2;
            this.field3 = field3;
            this.field4 = field4;
            this.field5 = field5;

        }
        /*---------Wraper Constructor--for Incoming section with Actual Recieved date is null------*/

         public wrapperPendingMilestone(SObject sobj, String objName, String field3,String field4,String field5){
            this.sobj = sobj;
            this.objName = objName;           
            this.field3 = field3;
            this.field4 = field4;
            this.field5 = field5;
        }             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the way you implemented it.

In your `displayList`, you are always carrying 10 items depending upon which page you are. So at any point of time, your `pageBlockTable` has 10 records in it. Now the `tablesorter` works on client side i.e your browser. So from `tablesorter`'s point of view, it only has 10 records in the table whose ID you have provided to tablesorter. Hence its working only on the current 10 records.

As a solution, you can either handle sorting & pagination both using apex class or both using javascript(i.e 3rd party JS library, [footable](http://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html#examples) is a good way to start)

Comment: Isn't there any way to let the table sorter know that there are 12 records?

Comment: That's something you need to check on tablesorter's documentation. But as far as I know normally you don't have that option unless you have the whole data in your table source.

Comment: Thanks for the info.i will look for the solution and wait for some more feedback before i close this question

Answer (score 0):

Either you can sort in apex code to by using following code:

```
public class PSS_PendingMilestonesControllerNew implements Comparable {
   List<wrapperPendingMilestone> wrapperListShow = new 

   List<wrapperPendingMilestone>();
   wrapperListShow.add(new wrapperPendingMilestone(parameters));
  .
  .
  .
  wrapperListShow.sort();
  public Integer compareTo(Object obj) {
       SelectOpt obj1 = (SelectOpt) obj;
       if (this.objName == obj1.objName) return 0;
       if (this.objName > obj1.objName) return 1;
       return -1;        
   }
}
```